# Shiny apps greyed out - nginx proxy over ssl

Tags: r, nginx, ssl, shiny, shiny-server

I am trying to secure access to some shiny apps being served over our web server via https and using auth0 for login. 
Shiny apps don't work over https, though they work over http.

System info:

- nginx/1.10.2
- Shiny Server v1.5.3.838
- Node.js v6.10.0
- CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)

console.log link https://gist.github.com/vasantm/4339b248143fa6b3f8c4d0f1773f33e9

nginx.conf link
https://gist.github.com/vasantm/d98c8ae9de8a8667d9d2e6e59945de62

shiny-server.conf link
https://gist.github.com/vasantm/43a94acd7b9fcf573cdea2a200218425.

I used this reference to configure nginx and shiny
[Running Shiny Server with a Proxy](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213733868-Running-Shiny-Server-with-a-Proxy)

Any clues to get shiny working over SSL?

Even after fixing typos and using the updated config,
I get greyed out apps.
Here's the updated console.log
I still get greyed out apps. I then uncommented the highlighted part of the config above and still got errors.

here's the latest console.log

WebSocket connection to 'wss://kristallab.bwh.harvard.edu/sample-apps/rmd/**sockjs**/n=DDUjuaZmdQBFbAe8Ni/345/w1oqw659/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400WrappedWebSocket @ VM220:35

VM221:35 WebSocket connection to 'wss://kristallab.bwh.harvard.edu/sample-apps/hello/**sockjs**/n=NCXw2RGlge88iybomV/805/n61pj5fb/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400WrappedWebSocket @ VM221:35
shiny-server-client.min.js:formatted:935Wed Jun 07 2017 18:08:39 GMT-0400 (EDT) [INF]: Error: WebSocket closed
shiny-server-client.min.js:formatted:935Wed Jun 07 2017 18:08:39 GMT-0400 (EDT) [INF]: Connection closed. Info: {"isTrusted":false}
shiny-server-client.min.js:formatted:265Wed Jun 07 2017 18:08:39 GMT-0400 (EDT) [DBG]: SockJS connection closed
shiny-server-client.min.js:formatted:265Wed Jun 07 2017 18:08:39 GMT-0400 (EDT) [DBG]: Channel 0 is closed
shiny-server-client.min.js:formatted:265Wed Jun 07 2017 18:08:39 GMT-0400 (EDT) [DBG]: Removed channel 0, 0 left
shiny-server-client.min.js:1 Wed Jun 07 2017 18:08:39 GMT-0400 (EDT) [INF]: Error: WebSocket closed
shiny-server-client.min.js:1 Wed Jun 07 2017 18:08:39 GMT-0400 (EDT) [INF]: Connection closed. Info: {"isTrusted":false}
shiny-server-client.min.js:1 Wed Jun 07 2017 18:08:39 GMT-0400 (EDT) [DBG]: SockJS connection closed
shiny-server-client.min.js:1 Wed Jun 07 2017 18:08:39 GMT-0400 (EDT) [DBG]: Channel 0 is closed
shiny-server-client.min.js:1 Wed Jun 07 2017 18:08:39 GMT-0400 (EDT) [DBG]: Removed channel 0, 0 left

Screenshots shown below
[image: Shiny apps greyed out over https]
[image: Shiny apps work fine over http]

Comment: Updated config file included at gist.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try adding these lines into your shiny conf file:

```
sanitize_errors off;disable_protocols xdr-streaming xhr-streaming iframe-eventsource iframe-htmlfile;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks. Could you tell what is the reason of this problem?

Comment: 100 likes, worked like a charm! One can also add these settings to a docker image: https://github.com/hemberg-lab/scmap-shiny/blob/3d3381aa9780b258e29afd6de0b08326a6571b44/Dockerfile#L20

Comment: A similar problem: no nginx, but ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse in Apache config. The graying out occurred only with certain versions of macOS as the client: 10.13.4 and 10.13.5. Earlier versions as well as 10.13.6 beta versions or under any other OS shiny worked fine. The choice of a web browser had nothing to do with the problem.

I added the lines above to my config file and it helped. Thanks!